# Node JS passport google oauth not working on https?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am getting really frustrated with this error. Here is the application that I have deployed to heroku https://emm-samrat.herokuapp.com. If you click on login button it shows a blank page. But if you change the https to http everything work as expected. Can you tell me what is happening?

Here is my code of passport.js

```
    passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: keys.googleClientId,
          clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
          //this is for production
          callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
          proxy: true
        },
        async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
          done(null, profile);
        }
      )
    );

  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      prompt: "select_account",
      session: false,
      scope: ["openid", "profile", "email"]
    })
  );

  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { session: false }),
    async (req, res) => {
      const user = await User.findOne({ authId: req.user.id });

      //Stores the User Google Profile ID in session
      req.session.authId = req.user.id;
      if (user) {
        res.redirect("/");
      }
      //If the user is visiting for the first time,
      //he/she should fill the additional form
      res.redirect("/signup");
    }
  );
```

EDIT: If your application makes the use of React. Make sure to delete `import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'` on index.js and delete all the browser cache. And everything will work as expected.

Comment: My guess is Google won't respond to unsecure requests and just becuase you have `https` in your url does not mean you have SSL certificate, you'll need to acquire one for your app. More on that here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#setting-up-ssl-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a SSL certificate, there are some free ones out there